# How to implement to_str or to_s

Tags: ruby, string, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, magic-methods

I have a class that should be used as a string and will always be a string (even if empty). The object will always have a string representation. The following is an example of my class:

```
class Something
    def initialize
        @real_string_value = "hello"
    end
    def to_s
        return @real_string_value
    end
    def to_str
        return @real_string_value
    end
end

text = Something.new
puts("#{text}") #=> #<Something:0x83e008c>
```

I ran this test on minitest:

```
assert_equal(
    "",
    "#{@text}",
    "Unchanged class should convert to empty by default"
)
```

The test above fails. Why isn't my class converted to a string?

Comment: I got `hello`: https://ideone.com/ofHJ4m

Comment: Why `#{@text}"` instead of `#{text}` in the test code?

Comment: The test is acting on an instance variable created in the minitest `setup` method.

Comment: I think the assertion should be: `assert_equal("hello", "#{@text}")` because the `to_s` return the string assigned to `@real_string_value`.

Comment: In this example, yes, but for my test no. It should return an empty string if no value was assigned to the class. However, let me assign it the value `hello` to see if that works.

Comment: Changed it to hello and got hello. I found my mistake. Should I delete the question?

Comment: How about post your mistake as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68124/discussion-between-dodzi-dzakuma-and-falsetru).

Answer (score 1):

The code print `hello` as expected if it's run as a script.

If you run the code in `irb` or similar interactive shell, it uses [`inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect) instead of [`to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method for the following line:

```
text = Something.new
```

---

You need to define `inspect`:

```
class Something

    ...

    def inspect
        to_s
    end
end
```